# Google Optimize JS API on SPA

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, google-optimize

I have a problem with the Google Optimize JS API on my SPA, the callback is only run on page reload but when navigating back and forward to the specific page, the callback isn't being run. Here's the scenario:

1) I reload the application and go to my page having an active A/B-test: mysite.com/testpage

2) The folowing code is being run:

```
gtag('event', 'optimize.callback', {
     name: experimentId,
     callback: useVariant,
});
```

and `useVariant(variantId)` is being called setting the correct variantId.

3) I click or navigate away from the page and then click/navigate back to mysite.com/testpage, this is a SPA mind you.

4) The `gtag()` code is being re-called, BUT the callback `useVariant()` isn't being run.

5) WTF.

6) If I reload the page, using CMD+R (yes, I'm using Mac), the code runs as in point 1) And everything is ok.

I have tried the following:

A. Resetting the datalayer using `google_tag_manager['xxx'].datalayer.reset()`

B. Re-pushing the event with undefined callback `gtag('event', 'optimize.callback', undefined)`

C. Resetting `datalayer = [] manually`

D. Removing the `optimize.callback` event from the datalayer

E. Any combination of above (which gives a bit interesting results sometime)

So the question is in point 5: WTF? Any suggestions/thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the trigger of your experiment? Page load or custom event?

Comment: Using redux useEffect in a Component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it! Here's how to fix it, maybe this will help someone else.

The problem is the callback function  `useVariant`. I had defined it as so `useVariant(variantId)` when apperantly (thanks Google documentation for being clear on this, NOT) it has to be `useVariant(variantId, experimentId)`

So by changing the callback function to take two arguments the code will work.

Comment: I have the same (or similar issue). This didn't fix it for me. I wonder if I have a different configuration "outside' of the `gtag('event', 'optimise.callback', /* ... */)` call.

Comment: Nothing more than this:

   `window.gtag('event', 'optimize.activate');
   window.gtag('event', 'optimize.callback', {
      name: experimentId,
      callback: useVariant,
   });`

Answer (score -1):

For React, you can implement Activation Events in your top-level component's `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle methods to run the experiment codes immediately after the component mounts or updates on the page.

Your code may look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
export default class App extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        dataLayer.push({ 'event': 'optimize.activate' });
    }
    componentDidUpdate() {
        dataLayer.push({ 'event': 'optimize.activate' });
    }
    render() {
        // experiment code goes here...
    }
}
```

[SPA tests on Google optimize](https://www.brillmark.com/how-to-run-a-b-tests-on-dynamic-pages-or-single-page-applications-spas-on-optimizely-and-google-optimize/)